# Retrieve data from Oracle 11g to Excel 2007 - Excel not responding

Tags: oracle, excel, oracle11g, vba

Houston, we have a problem! :)

I have some Excel files that connect through VBA to an Oracle 11g database using the OraOLEDB driver:

```
strConn = "User ID=<useridhere>" & _
    ";Password=<passwordhere>" & _
    ";Data Source=" & xServer & _
    ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle"
```

The problem happens when I run a SQL query like `SELECT * FROM <view_name_here>`. These queries run when the user clicks a button - that has a macro attached.

What I'm using to do the queries:

```
Sub Load_Data(ws As Worksheet, sSql As String)
    Dim oQt As QueryTable
    OpenConn
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sSql, sConn

    ws.Activate
    ClearActiveSheet

    Set oQt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(rs, ws.Cells(1, 1))
    oQt.Refresh
    rs.Close
    sConn.Close
End Sub
```

Note: `ws` is the worksheet that will display the data, `sSql` is the query to retrieve the data.

My problem is that Excel freezes - not responding - while retrieving data from the Oracle database - if I have 10 instances of Excel open, all will be unusable.

My objective is to have a "non-blocking" database access - if the query takes 10 minutes, I can still use excel.

If anyone can help me, that would be great :)

Note: I've attached all the pieces of code that I thought required. If you want to see anything else that can lead to a solution, just let me know.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I've managed to get it working with the following code:

```
Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=" & Server & ";" & "USER ID=" & UID & ";PASSWORD=" & PWD
Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Cmd.CommandText = sSql

Set RS = Cmd.Execute

For X = 0 To noLines
    Data.Cells(1, X + 1) = RS.Fields(X).Name
    Next
    Do While Not RS.EOF
        Row = Row + 1
        For Findex = 0 To RS.Fields.Count - 1
        Data.Cells(Row + 1, Findex + 1) = RS.Fields(Findex).Value
        Next Findex
        RS.MoveNext
    Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Calculate

Conn.Close
```

This **does** block the *current* file but not the remaining ones. That was the main goal.

Answer (score 1):

ADO provides a way of running queries asynchronously - Microsoft provides an example [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190988) that wraps the query in a class, declaring the `ADODB.Connection` using `WithEvents`.  It implements a function to handle the `ExecutionComplete` event of the ADODB.Connection object, and it opens the query using the `ADODB.Recordset`, the `ADODB.Connection` and the `adAsyncExecute` flag to return immediately and allow the interface to stay responsive.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll take a look at it, give it a try and will report the outcome.

Comment: I've tried your solution but I could not get it to work. I've edited my question in order provide my "yeah it's a kind of solution that kind of works" :)

Comment: @hardc0ded Ok, if you do decide that you want to try and get the "adAsyncExecute" method working, ask it as a new question, post some code, and either myself or another SO user should be able to get you on the right track.